# Adding loadTestsFromTestCase from a string

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating an application where I pass in one or more test cases to the TestLoader that then get run.

I can run and add the testcase to the suite like this

```
suite1 = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(mymodule.Testcase01)
suite = unittest.TestSuite([suite1])
```

However, what I actually want to do is something like this

```
myTestcaseAsString="mymodule.Testcase01"    
suite1 = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(myTestcaseAsaString)
suite = unittest.TestSuite([suite1])
```

What I want to happen is that the value of myTestcaseAsaString is passed into loadTestsFromTestCase as if it was hard coded like the first example

Is that possible? (my long term goal is to be able to add multiple testcases to teh same suite - if that makes a difference)

Thanks

Grant

Comment: You should modify the tags to be the language and/or test framework you're using.   Python, I think, but am not 100%.  This is not a selenium question.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing

```
suite2 = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(eval(testcasemodule))
```

I have full control over the testcasemodule value

Thanks

Grant